Automorphism group of primitive field extension?
I was faced with the problem earlier of finding the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ that fix $\mathbb{Q}$. My logic was understanding that the quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, which obviously induces only the trivial automorphism.
More broadly, I realized that if any extension over a field of characteristic zero is primitive, wouldn't that same logic also imply that all Galois groups are trivial? If someone could explain where my though process diverges from truth, I would appreciate it.

Any such automorphism maps an (algebraic) element to a root of its minimal polynomial. But $\alpha$ might not be the only such root in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. For $\sqrt[3]{2}$ this is indeed the case, but for $\sqrt{2}$ it isn't.

${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-1})$ has a very well-known nontrivial automorphism.
